# How to center align text in a HTML table cell, without considering other elements in the cell

Tags: html, css

How do I center text in a `div` in a column without counting other element in same `div`, please?

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
  </tr>
    <td>text2<button>ok</button></td>
  <tr>
    <td>text3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean "without counting other element in same div"?

Comment: And why is your question about divs but your example doesn't use any?

Comment: If you mean **ignoring** the other elements, you can't do that unless you use **absolute positioning**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to use `position:absolute;` on the button so it can be ignored and allow the text to be centered.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.okButton {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
  </tr>
  <td>text2<button class="okButton">ok</button></td>
  <tr>
    <td>text3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is about [clearing the float](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)ting elements or in other words about [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

**This should help you understand what is happening, then you can use it or avoid it**

exemple below using overflow to trigger the block formatting context on the div (table element do it naturally).

Your code initially did not trigger any block formatting context in your div, that's why it did not minfd the floatting element.

```css
td, div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow:hidden
}

button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<p>In a 'table'</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
  </tr>
    <td>text2<button>ok</button></td>
  <tr>
    <td>text3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>In a 'div' with block formatting context to mind the floatting button. </p>
<div>text1</div>
<div>text2<button>ok</button></div>
<div>text3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a class to your text and add the below

```
.yourclass{
    text-align: center;
}
```

in your css

Comment: He does have text-align set for all divs.